# problem in playlist when we select the different songs

Tags: php, html, xml, flash

Actually in my website www.musicking.in when the user selects songs one player window will open and that will access the corresponding selected songs xml playlist and the player will play those songs.

actually its working fine.
but sometimes the problem is when so many users are accesiing the player not playing the songs selected, either its playing songs previously he selected or nothing.

please help me.

{my player code}

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["song"])&& $_POST['song'] != "") 
    {
        $song = $_POST["song"];
    }
    else {$song=array();} 

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
// display document in browser as plain text 
// for readability purposes

// create root element
$root = $dom->createElement("playlist");
$dom->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute('version', "1");
$root->setAttribute('xmlns', "http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
$rootnext = $dom->createElement("trackList");
$root->appendChild($rootnext);
foreach ($song as $counter) {
    $tokens = ",";
    $tokenized = strtok($counter, $tokens);
// create child element

$song = $dom->createElement("track");
$rootnext->appendChild($song);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("creator");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode("www.musicking.in");
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$song1 = $dom->createElement("title");
$song->appendChild($song1);
// create text node
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$tokenized = strtok($tokens);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("location");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 

}
// save 
$dom->save("playlist.xml");
?>
<object data="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=playlist.xml" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="300"><param name="movie" value="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=playlist.xml"/></object>




{sample playlist.xml}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" version="1"><trackList><track><creator>www.musicking.in</creator><title>Ey Yavo </title><location>/telugusongs/prayanam/Ey Yavo.mp3</location></track><track><creator>www.musicking.in</creator><title>Meghamaa </title><location>/telugusongs/prayanam/Meghamaa.mp3</location></track><track><creator>www.musicking.in</creator><title>Nuvvu Entha </title><location>/telugusongs/prayanam/Nuvvu Entha.mp3</location></track></trackList></playlist>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is problem with the XML Generation? Do the lists come out wrong? Why do you save it to a file? Maybe the problem lies there?

Comment: then what i have to do?
otherthan saving to a file wat can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you always use the file playlist.xml, and so if there are 10k visitors that single file is overwritten 10k times. Usually no problem but the internet is slow and so if one clicks ur site, the xml is generated and the swf is loaded which then uses the xml. There are delays in it and it might come to problems if one clicks and before his player loaded another one created an xml.
I sugguest u use a variable filename (could be a random one)
U might have to clean up the old files time after time

Comment: can u please help me in creating variable file names?
i dont know how to do it.

Comment: You could either go totally random but i do not really like that.
One solution i would prefer is:
$string = explode(" ",microtime());
$string = $string[1] ."-". $string[0];
then in $string is a string that contains the startpoint very detailed so i think it is not possible that two users interfere and you could relatively easy clean up old files via the timestamp

Comment: where i have to use this
$string = explode(" ",microtime()); $string = $string[1] ."-". $string[0];

Comment: put it directly after "// save" and change the following line to:
$dom->save($string);
and after that replace the <object line with:

<object data="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=<?php $string ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="300"><param name="movie" value="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=<?php $string ?>"/></object>

Comment: its working but not perfect.......
when i select another movie songs ,it showing previously selected songs

Comment: The problem that occures because you have only one file is solved, this must have to do something with the part where you send the "song" variables to the php.
Do some serious debugging, but it looks like you have no clue of php and stuff so i recommend asking someone to do that help you with that, asking for every single step here might take endless time

Comment: ya am poor at php. and no one is here to help me.
i understood from above lines is
microtime() function is giving current unix time stamp and we are eliminating delimiters by using explode function
so we r giving different file names each time.

but its not working

Comment: of course if does. As someone said in one of you other questions, using a database would probably be better than those xml stuff. If you use xml 1 see 3 ways to do it:
a)As was before
b)As is now (many files)
c)one xml per song, but i think this might be problematic with playlists

You could delete old files automatically as the timestamp is in the filename, you just need a script for that. Your error must come from another part of the process, use "echo" and "var_dump" to look at certain variables at different times to determine where the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

Here's fast fix, but you really need to think this over.

Leave only this in that file:

```
if(isset($_POST["song"])&& $_POST['song'] != "") 
    {
        $song = $_POST["song"];
    }
    else {$song=array();} 
<object data="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=playlist.php?song=<?=$song; ?>"      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="300"><param name="movie"   value="musicplayer.swf?autostart=true&playlist=playlist.php?song=<?=$song; ?>"/></object>
```

Then make playlist.php file with all the generation stuff:

```
if(isset($_GET["song"])&& $_GET['song'] != "") 
    {
        $song = $_GET["song"];
    }
    else {$song=array();}

....old generation code....
// Instead of saving it now, you just echo it. 
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

This is just really fast fix, I can't guarantee it will work since it depends how your music player reads files. But this is the way you want to go. You want to generate playlist file based on song parameter and echo it to browser.